# Having trouble animating bitmap on a canvas with a custom view

Tags: android, animation, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to simulate animation using a custom View (called MyView). I am trying to show a bitmap moving across the screen. My plan is to have the View’s onDraw method draw the bitmap at a given x,y. I can increment x and redraw the bitmap. Here is some code:

**MyView**

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private Bitmap block;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.block = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.block);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        //block is a bitmap of a block…
        canvas.drawBitmap(block, MainActivity.x, 100, null);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static int x = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        myView.invalidate();

        Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
        butt.setOnClickListener((v) - > {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                x += 10;
                myView.invalidate();
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
            }
        });
    }
```

So, I see my `block` sitting on the left side of the screen, so far so good. When I press the button `butt`, what I thought would happen, is that I would see a 5 second animation of `block` moving across the screen at 2 FPS.

Instead, there is a 5 second delay with no change on screen, then the block has moved 100 pixels to the right. All of the "in between" frames in the for loop seem to have happened behind the scenes, and I just see where the block is at the end of the for loop.

**So how can I view the *"live"* animation; how can I make sure that the screen updates with each call to invalidate?**

Comment: use ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator inside your custom MyView

Comment: Also don't use loop with sleep, because you're not giving UI Thread time to redraw/refresh views (it just blocks the UI thread), either put it in postDelayed loop or use another thread

Comment: @pskink ValueAnimator did the trick, thanks!